# hyperledger fabric what's the difference between MSP idemix and x509(TCert ECert)?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, x509

I have seen the ECert and TCert on the fabric-ca docs, also there is a link which has [described](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABN-85)

> Overall flow is actually very similar to how TCert was done before, except that the client are not issued x.509 certificates, but instead idmixer credentials.

So, can I see it as the same besides the x509 and idemix things?

What's the difference? How does idemix can do the unreveal thing and ECert/TCert can't? They are both have one cert for membership and when it's coming to sign they will have another cert from ca.

If you may share anything you knew, thanks a lot!

Comment: after a year and I now know it a little more. The TCert or ECert is both ecdsa certs follow the x509 standerd. And ECert is using for sign / verify, mean time the TCert is working on the TLS communications. Since fabric is based on gRPC to communicate, when the TLS function has turned on, each Peer or Orderer or Client needs the TCert to secure the gRPC link, same as the SSL on https.

Comment: And idemix is just a identidy mix up tool. When you using it in your network, idemix will help you to cover your tracks, make the transaction untrace-able. More infomations you may checkout the offical docs in the Hoai's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idemix uses the zero-knowledge proofs, which help users hide their identity more efficient. Hyperledger Fabric has a document about this. You can find it [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/idemix.html#comparing-idemix-credentials-to-x-509-certificates).